# ActiveRecord: Add table name in where query even without join

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

I have this method

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.search(q, with_address)
    klass = self
    klass = klass.includes(:address) if with_address
    klass.where("users.name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%")
  end

end
```

I need to add the `users.name` in the query so that it knows to which table it refers. But when `:address` is not included, I have a message:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "users.name" does not exist
```

How can I enforce the table name prefix in the query? Something like `AS users` in SQL.

Using Rails 3.2

Thanks

Comment: Why are you building it like that?  Why not just have an if else with seperate queries rather than trying to dynamically build it based on the options provided to the method?

Comment: Because in the real method, I do more complex behavior where `q` can also be used to select over the `:address` table.

Comment: You can just try this klass.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{q}%")

Comment: I don't understand what is not working. You mean that you cannot do 
`User.where('users.name LIKE ?', "%#{q}%")` ? I don't see any reason why it should not work.

Comment: Because in the SQL query, the user table in not aliased as `users` as there is only 1 table involved: `select * from users where name = blahblah` and not `select * from users where users.name = blahblah`

Comment: Because when the methods translate into sql, User.where('name like ?',"whatever") becomes "SELECT 'users'.* FROM 'users' WHERE 'users'.'name' LIKE 'whatever'", so if you write "users.name" it will become "WHERE 'users'.'users'.'name'..."

Comment: Ok cool. The question remains unanswered but I guess it's because my strategy is really not a good practice in Rails ...